# Change div text scroll bottom jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Welcome. I have some problem with my website, which are building on wordpress. So I created website of fullpane theme wordpress and I want create some like index "x of x section" on the right side. You can see this on located in http://emotivo.pl/nowe/. I thinking about 01 / 05 on the right side on my website.
This should working in this way, when I scroll to bottom number should change from 01 / 05 to 05 / 05.
I tried with script which is added in footer before end tag body

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var children = $("#superContainer").children(); 
    $(children).each(function(index,value) {
    if($(value).hasClass("active")){
        $("div#date").html(index+" of "+ children.length);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

which help mi wrote some men from stackoverflow but isnt work properly.
Maybe someone know request form my ask?
Please help me with my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to watch for

```
$(window).scroll()
```

By inspecting your page I see your scrolling item has a **.scrollable** class.

Try to watch for

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(document).on('scroll', '.scrollable', function(){
    var children = $("#superContainer").children(); 
    $(children).each(function(index,value) {
    if($(value).hasClass("active"))
        $("div#date").html(index+" of "+ children.length);
    });
  });
});
```

In your script. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Unfortunatelly isnt work.. You tell me that I shoud replace this element in my script?

Comment: $('.scrollable').scroll(function(){/*Put your code inside here*/})

Comment: Also you have to put everything inside $(document).ready(function(){   }) otherwise it will be processed BEFORE the .scrollable creation

Comment: Is it should look like this?                                                                     <script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.scrollable').scroll(function(){
    var children = $("#superContainer").children(); 
    $(children).each(function(index,value) {
    if($(value).hasClass("active"))
        $("div#date").html(index+" of "+ children.length);
  });
});
});
</script>

Comment: Just incapsulate your code in the document ready function like this
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.scrollable').scroll(function(){......}) })

Comment: I should tell you that my english is poor so i dont understand how you thinking about it..

Comment: It should be ok, try to publish it